# Why prolog uses most-general-unifier and not simply unifier

Tags: prolog

Prolog uses most general unifier instead of just unifier, why is it so?

If I'm not wrong then I think that, since Prolog is based on backtracking and if we don't use most general unifier, then we miss certain combinations of unification of the variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the most general unifier and just a unifier shows when the resulting term still contains variables. Consider to most general unification problem:

```
?- X = Y.
```

A concrete unifier would be:

```
X = a, Y = a.
```

But also

```
X = 23, Y = 23.
```

and so on.

So there are many such possible outcomes.  However, we want to get **all of them**. That's what the most general unifier does:

```
X = Y.
```

or

```
Y = X.
```

There are still two of them, but this ambiguity is ignored adding "up to renaming (of variables)" should the context require it.